# ActionController::Dispatcher (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rack

I'm working along with the Rspec book. In chapter 19, they set up a testing environment for a Rails project

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "2.0.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
  gem "webrat", "0.7.2"
end
```

when I try to run cucumber I get this error.

```
bundle exec rake cucumber
/Users/kk/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
uninitialized constant ActionController::Dispatcher (NameError)
```

This part of the error message...

```
 Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
```

... is very common (according to a Google search). However, I can find anything about it in relation to my dev environment. Can anyone explain

This is my gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "2.0.0"
  gem "cucumber-rails", "0.3.2"
  gem "webrat", "0.7.2"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's still emitting part of the error message

```
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
```

I got cucumber to work, though I'm not exactly sure which step is responsible for the change.

I added the require statement.

```
 gem "cucumber-rails", "1.3.0", :require => false
```

I also added nokogiri to the gemfile.